# call server side inherited C# web method from javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

Please Help me,
I want to call a server side function in `page1` from `page2` using java script.

For example in `Home.aspx.cs` i have `read()` webmethod and i want to call this method from `Call.aspx`'s Javascript function.

Comment: Why not place the webmethod code in a separate webservice?

Comment: You need to use ajax

Comment: Hi Mr.White my aim is to call the server side method from javascript. so i feel a separate web service is not needed

Comment: Hi Erikscandola, am using javascript but i am receiving the error "read() method is unidentified"

Comment: call.aspx i am using the below code.

 <script type="text/javascript">
        function HandleOnclose(e) {
            debugger;
            //alert(userid);
            var clickY = window.event.clientX;

            var altKey = window.event.clientY < 0;
            if (clickY>0 && altKey==true)            
                PageMethods.UpdateUserLogoutStatus();
        }
        window.onbeforeunload = HandleOnclose;   
        </script>

in Home.aspx.cs 
[WebMethod]
        public static void UpdateUserLogoutStatus()
        {

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "linkToOtherPage",
    method: "POST", // or GET, I don't know what you need
    data: dataToPass,
    success: function (response) { },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { }
});
```